# How can I send HTML enquiry form data to multiple WhatsApp contact?

Tags: javascript, html, whatsapp

I have a HTML form that send form data to Whatsapp contact but I want to send same data to multiple WhatsApp contact and how can i make `input` field required?

HTML Form

```
`<form autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="Name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" value="" required="required" />
<input type="text" name="Email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" value="" required="required" />
<input type="number" name="Phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Contact Number *" value="" required="required" />
<select class="form-control" id="service">
<option>Default select</option>
<option>Website Development</option>
<option>Mobile App Development</option>
<option>Web and Mobile Application</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="submit" class="btnSubmit btn-block" onClick="gotowhatsapp()" value="Submit" />
</form>`
```

JS

```
<script>
function gotowhatsapp() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var service = document.getElementById("service").value;
var url = "https://wa.me/910123456789?text="
+ "Name: " + name + "%0a"
+ "Phone: " + phone + "%0a"
+ "Email: " + email + "%0a"
+ "Service: " + service;
window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Making an `input` `required` is as simple as using a `required` attribute, like

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" value="" required />
```

As about sending it to multiple items, you can change your function to

```
function gotowhatsapp(urls) {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var service = document.getElementById("service").value;
    for (let u of urls) {
        var url = "https://wa.me/" + u + "?text="
        + "Name: " + name + "%0a"
        + "Phone: " + phone + "%0a"
        + "Email: " + email + "%0a"
        + "Service: " + service;
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
}
```

and you can pass for `urls` something like

```
[
    'abc',
    'def'
]
```